# undefined local variable or method `config' for main:Object (NameError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, undefined

I'm writing a rails app and I'm trying to use [Devise](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/). Following the [setup instructions here](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise#getting-started), I am trying to do `rails generate devise:install`, but I keep getting this error:

```
~/projects/readone/config/application.rb:8:in `<top (required)>': undefined local variable or method `config' for main:Object (NameError)
```

I tried different things like uninstalling, reinstalling the gem, etc.  I also found some similar errors on Google and elsewhere on Stack Overflow, but none of them had to do specifically with this `` undefined local variable or method `config' `` error.

I'll include the full error below.  Any idea what might be happening?

```
~/readone/config/application.rb:8:in `<top (required)>': undefined local variable or method `config' for main:Object (NameError)
from /~/.rbenv/versions/2.1.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/spring-1.2.0/lib/spring/application.rb:82:in `require'
from /~/.rbenv/versions/2.1.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/spring-1.2.0/lib/spring/application.rb:82:in `preload'
from /~/.rbenv/versions/2.1.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/spring-1.2.0/lib/spring/application.rb:143:in `serve'
from /~/.rbenv/versions/2.1.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/spring-1.2.0/lib/spring/application.rb:131:in `block in run'
from /~/.rbenv/versions/2.1.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/spring-1.2.0/lib/spring/application.rb:125:in `loop'
from /~/.rbenv/versions/2.1.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/spring-1.2.0/lib/spring/application.rb:125:in `run'
from /~/.rbenv/versions/2.1.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/spring-1.2.0/lib/spring/application/boot.rb:18:in `<top (required)>'
from /~/.rbenv/versions/2.1.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
from /~/.rbenv/versions/2.1.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
from -e:1:in `<main>'
```

Comment: Found the issue: I had a line in my config that said `config.force_ssl = true`.  Commented it out and it worked!

Considered deleting my question, but thought that maybe someone else might run into this sometime.

Comment: show code here: `~/readone/config/application.rb:8`

Comment: @МалъСкрылевъ : yep, that's what i was referring to in my own comment. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the issue: I had a line in my config that said config.force_ssl = true. Commented it out and it worked! Considered deleting my question, but thought that maybe someone else might run into this sometime. –